# PHP - a good way to split up into lines and add prefix and suffix

Tags: php, arrays

OK let's say I want to take this piece of text:

text ex 1.

```
  6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,  95,  95,  95,  51,
  6,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,   6,  95,  95,  95,  51,
  6,  60,  35,  35,  35,  35,  60,   6,   6,   6,  95,  95,
  6,  60,  35,  35,  35,  35,  60,  60,   6,   6,   6,   6,
  6,  60,  35,  35,  35,  35,  35,  60,   6,   6,   6,   6,
  6,  60,  35,  35,  35,  35,  35,  60,   6,  95,  95,  95,
  6,  60,  60,  21,  60,  60,  60,  60,   6,  95,  95,  51,
  6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,  95,  95,  51
```

and want to turn it into

text ex 2.

```
{  6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,  95,  95,  95,  51, },
{  6,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,   6,  95,  95,  95,  51, },
{  6,  60,  35,  35,  35,  35,  60,   6,   6,   6,  95,  95, },
{  6,  60,  35,  35,  35,  35,  60,  60,   6,   6,   6,   6, },
{  6,  60,  35,  35,  35,  35,  35,  60,   6,   6,   6,   6, },
{  6,  60,  35,  35,  35,  35,  35,  60,   6,  95,  95,  95, },
{  6,  60,  60,  21,  60,  60,  60,  60,   6,  95,  95,  51, },
{  6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,  95,  95,  51, },
```

using PHP. I would plop text ex 1. into a HTML form and using PHP... out would display for text ex 2...

How can this be achieved? Array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
<?php

//Process the form post
if($_POST['text_to_format']){
    $sFormatText = fncProcessText($_POST['text_to_format']);
}else{
    $sFormatText = 'Put Text Here';
}

?>

<html>

    <form id="format" action="/test.php" method="post">
        <textarea name="text_to_format"><?php echo $sFormatText ?></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Format">
    </form>

</html>

<?php

//Text Formatting Function
function fncProcessText( $sText = null ){

    //Make sure something is in $sText
    if($sText){
        //Create an array by splitting on line breaks
        $aText = explode("\r\n", $sText);

        //Glue the array together with the desired formatting
        return "{" . implode("},{\n", $aText) . "},";
    }else{
        return 'Put Text Here';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Looks promising! However the function fncProccessText makes the HTML form disappear. When I remove the function... the form appears...

Comment: I noticed that it was missing a semi-colon after return and changed action to "filenamehere.php" and method to "post" and now I am getting back "{Array}," inside the Textarea

Comment: sorry, i didn't test that code before posting it. i'll take a look.

Comment: Fixed it! Nice. But anyway so it's formatted nicely... right now it's like this:

{  6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,  95,  95,  95,  51,
},{
  6,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,   6,  95,  95,  95,  51,

Comment: I mean in here `51, },{ 6, 60,` there is a line break between the `,` and `{` so the `{` is on a line all by itself...

Comment: try exploding on "\r\n"... I just updated the code above to do just that.